# React js - state changing onclick from array of values - "Uncaught Invariant Violation" error

Tags: reactjs

Have an array of color options, want to create a dynamic list of these items then change the state to that selected color on click.

Here is my current code:

```html
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

const colors=["white","green","blue", "red", "orange"];

class Grid extends React.Component{

  constructor(props){    
    super(props);
    this.state={
      color: colors[0]
    };  
  }

  setCurrentColor(setColor){  
    this.setState({
      color: setColor
    });
  }
 
  setColorSelections(){
    const colorItems = colors.map((thecolor) =>
      <li  
      onClick={(thecolor) => this.setCurrentColor(thecolor)  }
      key={thecolor} >
      {thecolor}
      </li>
    );
    return(
      <ul>        
        {colorItems}
      </ul>
    ) 
  }
 
  render(){
    return(
      <div> 
        <p>Current selection: {this.state.color}</p>
              {this.setColorSelections()}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Receiving the following error

```html
Uncaught Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child
```

I really can't output the state? How do I fix this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the paramater `thecolor` from `onClick` function or rename it to something, it's giving you an error because the variable was declared in the map function `map((thecolor)`

```
setColorSelections() {
  const colorItems = colors.map((thecolor) =>
    <li
      onClick={(event) => this.setCurrentColor(thecolor)}
      key={thecolor} >
      {thecolor}
    </li>
  );
  return (
    <ul>
      {colorItems}
    </ul>
  )
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.21.1/babel.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>

<script type="text/babel">
const colors = ["white", "green", "blue", "red", "orange"];

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      color: colors[0]
    };
  }

  setCurrentColor(setColor) {
    this.setState({
      color: setColor
    });
  }

  setColorSelections() {
    const colorItems = colors.map((thecolor) =>
      <li
        onClick={(event) => this.setCurrentColor(thecolor)}
        key={thecolor} >
        {thecolor}
      </li>
    );
    return (
      <ul>
        {colorItems}
      </ul>
    )
  }
  render() {
    return (
    <div> 
        <p style={{ backgroundColor: this.state.color }}>Current selection: {this.state.color}</p>
              {this.setColorSelections()}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
</script>
```